# Modify PHP formatted variable to include spanish character

Tags: php

I have this php $regex var that stores allowed special characters. I would like to modify it, in order to `include spanish character ñ`, but It's a bit messy, and I don't understand how to do this.

Could someone please explain how this variable is structured and how can I add ñ to it?

```
//bug 40068, According to rules in page 6 of http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3696.html#sec-3, 
//allowed special characters ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ?  ^ _ ` . { | } ~ in local part 
var $regex = "/^(?:['\.\-\+&#!\$\*=\?\^_`\{\}~\/\w]+)@(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|\w+(?:[\.-]*\w+)*(?:\.[\w-]{2,})+)\$/";
```

Later in the code, they do this, I guess to do the validation:

```
if(!preg_match($this->regex, $email))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$regex = "/^(?:['\.\-\+&#!\$\*=\?\^_`\{\}~\/\wñ]+)@(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|[\wñ]+(?:[\.-]*[\wñ]+)*(?:\.[\wñ-]{2,})+)\$/";
```

The above **regular expression** will work and include the the `Spanish character ñ`

Comment: @JackCasas: ou are welcome, can you accept the answer if it worked, so that it would be helpful for all who visit the thread.